# requiredif entity framework empty field

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am validating a field based on another field using custom validation in MVC and I came across this implementation:

```
 public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private String PropertyName { get; set; }
        private String ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        private Object DesiredValue { get; set; }

        public RequiredIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredvalue, String errormessage)
        {
            this.PropertyName = propertyName;
            this.DesiredValue = desiredvalue;
            this.ErrorMessage = errormessage;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
        {
            Object instance = context.ObjectInstance;
            Type type = instance.GetType();
            Object proprtyvalue = type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance, null);
            if (proprtyvalue.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString())
            {
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

And I have a simple class defined as follows:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string name { set; get; }
    [RequiredIf("name","","Address is required")]
    public string addr { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the page, I get a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error but changing the line to `[RequiredIf("name","John","Address is required")]` yields expected results. My question is, how do you use it to check if the field is empty.

I have also tried changing the line to `[RequiredIf("name",null,"Address is required")]` but I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
        {
            if (value != null) { return ValidationResult.Success; }

            Object instance = context.ObjectInstance;
            Type type = instance.GetType();
            Object proprtyvalue = type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance, null);
            if (proprtyvalue == null) {
               return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the actual Person instantiations that you're testing, so I'm just guessing: make sure that **proprtyvalue** of PropertyName is not null before trying to call ToString() on it. So your **Person.Name** cannot be **null**!